# How can I reduce the size of my repository?

Tags: git

I have big git repository. And size of dotgit folder very big.(350gb - ty for our 3d modellers :))  I have 240gb free space in hard disk. When i have tried to run this command:

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

I got some error:

```
can't allocate memory...lalala
```

What should I do with this?  Should I  go to the git server and run this command there?

Comment: The caption and content of your question are basically two different questions. Do you want to keep your history or not?

Comment: @RolandSmith ty for answer. Sorry.  Yes I want to keep history since 2016 year. And want to clear dotgit folder

Comment: The `.git` directory is where your history is. You can't completely clear it and keep *any* of your history. I think you want to clear *some* of your history, but you need to update the question with more details about just what you want to do.

Comment: When asking for help it's *really important* to include the whole error message else we might not be able to help. The "lalala" means something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository has probably committed a lot of large files over time. Chopping off your history doesn't really help, the problem will come back as more large files get added and worked on, and you will have lost the history of your work.

Instead of committing large files directly, use [Git Large File Storage (git-lfs)](https://git-lfs.github.com/). This will allow you to commit large files and retain history without ballooning the repository size.

What about all those old commits? Rather than just chopping off your history at an arbitrary date, use the [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to clean large files from your history. This would allow you to retain your history while eliminating only the biggest offending files.

***Even better*** is you can combine the two! BFG can convert your existing big file commits into small git-lfs commits with the recently added `--convert-to-git-lfs`. [It's all documented in this blog post](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5). This is the best of both worlds: you keep all your history, all your files, and you get a slim repository. Once that's done, use `git-lfs` for all future large files.

Comment: Ty! I'll try this!