# I can't sync my git commits after adding, then removing, large csv files

Tags: git, github

I added some large csv files to a Git repo not knowing that Git does not allow such large files. I had already committed the files, so then I deleted them and committed those deletions ( all done with Github Desktop). However, I have not been able to sync any commits since that time. As of now:

- The csv files are not in my git directory.
- I have also added `*.csv` to my .gitignore file.
- I have also run a `git rm *.csv` in the relevant directories.

  None of this has helped. I am still getting the following error every time I try to sync:

> GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage...File subdir/large.csv os 256 MB. This exceeds GitHub's file
>   size limit of 100.00 MB.

What could be going wrong here, and how can I get back to syncing with my remote repo?

Comment: The limitation is with GitHub, not with Git itself.  Also note that the very first result for "remove large file from git" is GitHub's [own documentation for this issue](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/).

Comment: That might not seem like a duplicate, but it is. You should follow [my answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36779028/14660) and use the latest BFG with git-lfs support.